# Обнаружение строки-палиндрома

Tags: javascript, строки

Прошу подсказать наиболее эффективный способ обнаружения строки-палиндрома. Основной камень преткновения - символы пунктуации и иже с ними. Сама реализация алгоритма мне видится как сравнение первого элемента строки с последним, второго с предпоследним и так далее. Иначе говоря как-то так:

```
for (var arr = 'Аргентина манит негра!'
         i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] !== a[a.length - (i + 1)]) {
       result = -1;
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Оставь регэкспом только буквы, реверсни и сравни.

Comment: Эх.. нехватает метки код-гольф

Answer (score 4):

```js
function isPalindrome(str) {
  let s = str.toLowerCase().replace(/[^а-яё]/g, '');
  return s == [...s].reverse().join('');
}

console.log(isPalindrome('Аргентина манит негра!'))
console.log(isPalindrome('Аргентина манит афроамериканца?'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log('Аргентина манит негра!'.toLowerCase().match(/[а-яё]/g).every((c,i,a)=>c===a[a.length-(i+1)]))
```

Comment: чтобы проверить колличество элементов не обязательно из Set делать массив, а если вместо map использовать every - то и Set не нужен

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо, поправил. `every ` как-то выпало из внимания.